# Vertical Align Radio and Checkbox Button Labels and Input Elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have looked at other vertical align questions and answers but cannot seem to find an answer that works. I was wondering if any of you clever people knew how to fix my problem. And how deep I may have gone into my hole.

You can view my code here: https://github.com/LukeBennettUK/techdegree_project_3

[image: Problem]

I am trying to align these together. I have tried making them flex items and then adding margin-bottom. But the bottom item seems to have a larger margin between the one above for some reason like below:

[image: Help]

Very fussy I know. But I just want them all to be aligned correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Could you include a snippet in your question?

Comment: we are not going to download your whole project then run it and then find the relevant code ... you have to do this effort if you want SO to do the effort of helping you

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: Sorry abot not including a snippet. I thought the link would be quite easier and people may prefer it than having masses of code in the question. The people below have answered my question however I will bear in mind what you have said for the future! :) Thank you for trying to take a look. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is magical and it's going to change your life. I haven't used float in my code for the past year and I'm loving it! LOL

In the example below I apply flex to the parent container that holds the input and label. `justify-content` aligns everything to the left while `align-items` perfectly centers all children inside.

Here is an excellent resource that will teach you all of the cool layouts you can build with flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}

.newsletter-row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="newsletter-row">
     <input type="checkbox" id="css_nl" value="css" name="css_news">
     <label for="css_nl">CSS News</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! This really helped me figure out what the hell was going on with my code. I figured out it was the margin. But the flexbox really helped to easily align the labels. Now it looks great. Thank you so much for your time spent looking at my work. I really really do appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

idk how you broke it but here's a solution. your check boxes have 15px margin on right and bottom. put 15px all around and that will do the trick. I downloaded your code and tested it myself. [image: here's how I made it look]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It was my margins messing everything up. I should have just been using a margin-right property to move the label away from the input. Then I used the margin-bottom property on the newsletter-row instead of on the input field itself. Thank you for helping. I really really appreciate it!